# How to browse/find telegram channels and bots?

Tags: telegram

Imagine I would like to join a channel that is about Food. I can't find a way to search for it and find one. Of course channel should be public, but where/how should I search to find channels and bots on telegram?

I tried Googling with `site:telegram.me` to limit the choices to that site, but no result.

Comment: you can use this website https://xtea.io/ts_en.html to find whatever you want.

Comment: Google Search results are no longer organic, and blocks many of Telegram results. So you should use some other search engine like bing.com to do the search. Try searching for `covid vaccination site:t.me` in Google; and you'll find only two results. On Bing however, there are *many* channels in the results.

Answer (score 7):

There are third party catalogs of channels like:

https://www.reddit.com/r/TelegramChannels/

Answer (score 0):

You can find channels, groups, and bots in here: 
https://telegramchannels.me/

Answer (score 0):

You can find Telegram channels, groups and bots in the Telegram Directory https://tdirectory.me

Also you can find related channels/groups/bots, search by keyword/name and find the top listings for each category.